# creating a class for the first time, and am having issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting bound method division.common_divisor of **main**.division object...error.
I'm guessing I should just use a function instead of a class?

```
class division(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def divisor(self):
        div_list=[]
        i = 1
        while i<self.x:
            if self.x%i == 0:
                div_list.append(i)
            i+=1
        return div_list
    def common_divisor(self):
        sml1=divisor(self.x)
        sml2=divisor(self.y)
        common_lst=[]
        for i in sml1:
            for char in sml2:
                if i==char:
                    common_lst.append(i)
        return common_lst
check = division(10,20)
print (check.common_divisor)
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few errors in your code:

1)

```
print (check.common_divisor)
```

This line doesn't print result of calling `common_divisor` method, it just prints method without calling it - you forgot to add `()`: `print(check.common_divisor())` will be correct

2) In your `common_divisor` method you call `divisor` function but it's not defined. You tried to call `divisor` method, I suppose: `self.divisor()` will do it

3) In `divisor` method you use `self.x` instead of passed parameter from `common_divisor` method

4) In your code you missed case when one number is divider of second one:

```
while i < x:
```

won't return number as its own divider

Fixed code:

```
class division(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def divisors(self, x):
        div_list = []
        i = 1
        while i <= x:
            if x % i == 0:
                div_list.append(i)
            i += 1
        return div_list

    def common_divisor(self):
        sml1 = self.divisors(self.x)
        sml2 = self.divisors(self.y)
        common_lst = []
        for i in sml1:
            for char in sml2:
                if i == char:
                    common_lst.append(i)
        return common_lst

check = division(10, 20)
print(check.common_divisor())
```

Output:

> [1, 2, 5, 10]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ingvar I was able to see what I did wrong, here is the final functional code.
class division(object):
    def **init**(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def divisorX (self):
        div_list=[]
        i = 1
        while i